# Where should the api request should be written in MTV?

Tags: django

I have a web page that requesting authenticate user, retrieving and storing twitter data stream and performing some logic.

Where should the authenticate code to be written to retrieve and stored in database, is it model or view (because there is logic involved )?

So far I have written code for authentication and retrieve in model, but which is better?

```
.
|-- authenticate
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- initapp.json
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
|-- makefile
|-- manage.py
|-- README
|-- README.md
|-- template
|   |-- register.html
|   `-- search.html
|-- twitcount
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- admin.pyc
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
`-- twitting
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __init__.pyc
    |-- settings.py
    |-- settings.pyc
    |-- urls.py
    |-- urls.pyc
    |-- wsgi.py
    `-- wsgi.pyc
```

Comment: You can create logics.py, const.py, forms.py, processors.py, exceptions.py, tests.py etc.. next in views.py you can always import methods from logics.py or utils.py or constant variables from const.py etc. Keep it clean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **create another file** called `utils.py` or `twit_data.py`.

This file can reside either in `authentication` or `twitcount` **app** because it is related to both twitter and authentication.

You can however break the code into functions e.g authentication code should remain in `authentication` app and fetching twitter data code can be moved to a function in `twitcount/utils.py`.e.g

```
# twitcount/utils.py
def fetch_twitter_data(user):
   ...... logics.......
```

--

```
# authentication/views
from twitcount.utils import fetch_twitter_data

new_user = User.objects.get()
fetch_twitter_data(new_user)
```

**This helps in making code more generic and usable in other parts of application as well.**